# Specifying the types of parameters in a function that takes 2 parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a function that takes two parameters as below. If they are in an object, I can specify their types as follows

```js
    const renderItem = ({ item, index }: { item: string, index: number }) => {

        return (
            null
            )
    }
```

If parameters are not in an object like below, how can I specify their type?

```js
const renderItem = (item, index) => {

    return (
        null
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tuple type. This makes typing multiple parameters with a single type possible.

```
const renderItem = (...[item, index]: [string, number]) => {}
```

Or give each parameter its own explicit type.

```
const renderItem = (item: string, index: number) => {}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUzAEwXAklBBbGBeGACgDpSBtASy2wBoYKUEAPAXQC4Yzo4GBzOsAFdsAIzQsAlPgB8MAN4BfIA)